# Generic Timer/Worker Function

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I want to be able to perform workloads at intervals.
I want to be able to make this class generic so I can pass it whatever "workload" I want and my timer function just does it. I also would like a means of "returning" the workload response back to the caller.

As an example. Let's say I have a series of classes I have built that download data from a JSON API, or scrape a web page. This web scraper/API downloader needs to download pages from a site at different intervals. Each page will take a different number of parameters. I have found something online that indicates setting the Elapsed event to a delegate. This "may"work but I need to have the passed in delegate "dynamic" itself. So the Start method below which accepts a Func won't be correct from a "generic" standpoint, which is what I am after.
The solution itself is just an example of a line of thinking. Am open to other generic alternatives that help me achieve this.

```
public abstract class TimerWorkerDelegate : IDisposable, ITimerWorker
    {
        protected System.Timers.Timer DataTimer;
        public virtual void Start(Func<string> callback,double interval)
        {
            DataTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            DataTimer.Interval = interval;
            DataTimer.Elapsed += delegate {
                callback();
            };

            if (!DataTimer.Enabled)
                DataTimer.Enabled = true;
    //IDisposable code    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand 100% what you are REALLY trying to achieve, but... maybe something like.

```
public class Worker<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<T> OnCompleted;

    public Worker()
    {}

    public Worker(Func<T> fn, int interval)
    {
        Func = fn;
        Interval = interval;
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        if (Func == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(Interval);
            try
            {
                var result = Func();
                OnCompleted(this, result);
            }
            catch
            {
                return; // handle
            }
        }
    }

    public Func<T> Func { get; set; }

    public int Interval { get; set; }
}
```

And then `usage` in Console tester app as

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var worker = new Worker<string>
    {
        Interval = 1000,
        Func = () => { return string.Format("did some work at {0}", DateTime.Now); }
    };
    worker.OnCompleted += (sender, result) => { Console.WriteLine(result); };
    worker.Start();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look at it shortly. I guess the aim of the game is to be able to take a piece of work and apply automation to it. But the trick being, I want the "automation" to be in such a way that it is generic. Insofar as, my example - Web scraping with multiple/varying parameter counts. Or if that "work" was to read a file periodically, then my "automatiion"/"generic" worker should/would be able to achieve this.

Comment: Hello Mikko - I've just had a look at this. (Sorry for the delay i am still on vacation). I've just put this into a quick gui implementation (Winforms).The Issue I have here is that what if the passed in Func<T> needs to have multiple parameters passed into it? I not only need to make the return type Generic, which is easily solved by T, but any piece of work might have a different parameter count (and possibly of different types, not just string). Am I missing something elementary here?

Comment: Well.. You could make Worker accept multiple T params but would if be good if you create some common "UnitOfWork" class and use that in Worker? Then you could have any type of input you'd like. One property in this class could be "Params" array.

Comment: @The_Chud need ab example on what I'm after?

Comment: Hello Mikko that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a library you could look at [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive)

With it you could setup something very easily to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Below is a *very* rudimentary implementation of something that could work for you:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var scheduled = Schedule(
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        () => Console.WriteLine($"The current time is: {DateTime.Now}"));

    Console.ReadLine();

    // Dispose will stop the scheduled action
    scheduled.Dispose();
}

public IDisposable Schedule<T>(TimeSpan interval, Func<T> func)
    => Observable.Interval(interval).Subscribe(_ => func());

public IDisposable Schedule(TimeSpan interval, Action action)
    => Observable.Interval(interval).Subscribe(_ => action());
```